# .NET Core identity user id comes differently from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

I am trying to get current user's id with identity in .NET Core. Managed to create new user and login with it but whenever logging in with same user identity returns different guid.

I have a product entity which stores `userId` as foreign key. Whenever I try to add new product it throws error because given `userId` is not in user table.

But I register a new user and go add new product immediately it works. Lists products. However, logout and login again with same user, products are not listed. When I debug it saw that the `_userManager.GetUserId(User)` returning a different value.

Why could it be happened?

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
**My User Creation Code**

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

**My User Login Code**

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

**Here is My ApplicationUser Model Class**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    [Key]
    [Column("TABLEID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("AD")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("SOYAD")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("AKTIF")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("SIL")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("KAYITTARIHI")]
    public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }

    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public List<VehicleImage> VehicleImages { get; set; }
    public List<TransportAdvertise> TansportAdvertises { get; set; }
    public List<TransportRequest> TransportRequests { get; set; }

}
```

**Here is My DbContext**

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VehicleImage> VehicleImages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransportAdvertise> TransportAdvertises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransportRequest> TransportRequests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransportRoute> TransportRoutes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Identity built-in models.
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("TBLKULLANICI");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("TBLROL");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("TBLKULLANICIROL");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("TBLROLECLAIM");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("TBLUSERCLAIM");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("TBLUSERLOGIN");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("TBLUSERTOKEN");

        // Custom models.
        builder.Entity<Vehicle>().ToTable("TBLARAC");
        builder.Entity<VehicleImage>().ToTable("TBLARACRESIM");
        builder.Entity<TransportAdvertise>().ToTable("TBLNAKLIYEILAN");
        builder.Entity<TransportRequest>().ToTable("TBLNAKLIYEISTEK");
        builder.Entity<TransportRoute>().ToTable("TBLROTA");
        builder.Entity<City>().ToTable("TBLSEHIR");

        // FK mappings..
        builder.Entity<Vehicle>()
                .HasOne(v => v.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.Vehicles)
                .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_VEHICLE_USER");

        // Vehicle image model fks.
        builder.Entity<VehicleImage>()
                .HasOne(vi => vi.Vehicle)
                .WithMany(v => v.Images)
                .HasForeignKey(vi => vi.VehicleId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_VEHICLE_IMAGE_VEHICLE");

        builder.Entity<VehicleImage>()
                .HasOne(vi => vi.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.VehicleImages)
                .HasForeignKey(vi => vi.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_VEHICLE_IMAGE_USER");

        // TransportAdvertise model fks.
        builder.Entity<TransportAdvertise>()
                .HasOne(ta => ta.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.TansportAdvertises)
                .HasForeignKey(ta => ta.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_TRANSPORT_ADS_USER");

        builder.Entity<TransportAdvertise>()
                .HasOne(ta => ta.Vehicle)
                .WithMany(v => v.TransportAdvertises)
                .HasForeignKey(ta => ta.VehicleId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_TRANSPORT_ADS_VEHICLE");

        // TransportRequest model fks.
        builder.Entity<TransportRequest>()
                .HasOne(tr => tr.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.TransportRequests)
                .HasForeignKey(tr => tr.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_TRANSPORT_RQST_USER");

        builder.Entity<TransportRequest>()
                .HasOne(tr => tr.TransportAdvertise)
                .WithMany(ta => ta.TransportRequests)
                .HasForeignKey(tr => tr.TransportAdvertiseId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_TRANSPORT_RQST_ADS");

        // TransportRoute model fks.
        builder.Entity<TransportRoute>()
                .HasOne(tr => tr.City)
                .WithMany(c => c.TransportRoutes)
                .HasForeignKey(tr => tr.CityId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_TRANSPORT_ROUTE_CITY");

        builder.Entity<TransportRoute>()
                .HasOne(tr => tr.TransportAdvertise)
                .WithMany(ta => ta.TransportRoutes)
                .HasForeignKey(tr => tr.TransportAdvertiseId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_TRANSPORT_ROUTE_ADS");

    }
```

**Vehicle Creation Code**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddNewVehicle(VehicleViewModel model)
    {
        var id = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

        // model property check needs to be done before.
        // vehicle table does not accept nulls.

        var vehicle = new Vehicle()
        {
            Model = model.Model,
            Capacity = model.Capacity,
            Description = model.Description,
            Year = model.Year,
            Active = true,
            Delete = false,
            RecordDate = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = id
        };

        _vehicleService.AddNew(vehicle);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple experiment... Create a new user and note its Id... Immediately add a product and check again if the user ID has changed after the save operation. It is possible the user details is being mutated/changed upon save operation. You can also paste the code samples for creating a user, creating a product and retrieving a user here. The problem is most likely where u are saving the vehicles. At that point the user details is either being mutated, or the vehicles is being stored with a different user.  The vehicles has a 1 to 1 relationship with the user. So when creating a vehicle be careful not to be doing `vehicle.user = new User;`  Ensure you are doing the following. 
1- Get the user from the Db :

> var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync("Id of currently logged in
>   user");

2- set vehicle.user to the user retrieved above:

> vehicle.user = user.

You can share code where u are saving vehicle for people to be able to help. Also you can prevent the user Id from being automatically generated in the db and add a [Required] attribute on the Id field. You can the do

> user.Id = Guid.Guid.NewGuid()

.  This can help prevent issues where a new user is automatically added to the db when u create a vehicle

Comment: I have already done this. I recognise that the 'id' of the current user coming different from database after login. Aldo I have added the code snippets from the project. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is definitely where u are saving the vehicles.  The vehicles has a 1 to 1 relationship with the user. So when creating a vehicle be careful not to be doing vehicle.user = new User;

Comment: I dont think the problem is that. Becouse I am creating Vehicles by ataching UserId to the object. But the userId property does not come correctly. I am getting it as _userManager.GetUserId(User) but it never returns the correct ID. The returned value is never matching with database User table primary keys. There is not even a record with that id.

Comment: Updated questtion and shared the Vehicle creation post method. I have injected UserManager dependency to VehicleController and just trying to get current user id.

Comment: Then check your connection string. if you are using a defaultconnection string in your identityDbcontext configuration. In your identityModel do the following chnage  public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }  to    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyConnectionString") { }

Comment: I am sending a DbContext option to the context in startup like:
services.AddDbContext<TransportContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); And this 'DefaultConnection' is defined in aplicationsettins.json file.

Comment: It registers, logins everythin is fine but cannot get logged in user id correctly from database.

Comment: Define a connection string and use it instead of DefaultConnection. It most likely created a different database instance

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could not figure out how to solve this problem and decided to establish the structure over again. Now it works well. I think, I have made a mistake while writing models.